# xPath preceding doesn't work when node not exist

Tags: xml, xpath

For example xml:

```
<ul id="list">
<li>
    <h3 class="title">
    <a>text 1</a>
    </h3>
</li>
<li>
    <h3 class="title">
    <a>text 2</a>
    </h3>
</li>
<li>
    <h3 class="title">
    <a>text 3</a>
    </h3>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="sifExp">
        <span>...</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <h3 class="title">
    <a>text 4</a>
    </h3>
</li>
</ul>
```

The xPath preceding:

```
//ul[@id='list']//div[@class='sifExp']/preceding::li//h3[@class='title']/a
```

Working fine. The result is:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

But when a xml doesn't have a `<div class="sifExp">` node, the above expression doesn't work.

1. Why?
2. Is there way to get all content (`text 1, text 2, text 3, text 4`) when node `<div class="sifExp">`not exist?

Comment: Did you forget something? You mentioned "the following expression", but you gave no following expression. Or are you talking about the `following::` axis? I see no use of this axis either.

Comment: My mistake. I want to write "the above expression" (`//ul[@id='list']//div[@class='sifExp']/preceding::li//h3[@class='title']/a`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's find `li` which has not before `div[@class='sifExp']`. If it's not present, all `li`s are suitable

```
//ul[@id='list'] 
/li[not(preceding-sibling::li[div[@class='sifExp']])] 
/h3[@class='title']/a
```

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!

Comment: @mpietrewicz, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.